# JQuery second radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble updating the second radio button value on a JQuery page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="system-modes-fpa" class="ui-buttonset">
    <input type="radio" id="system-fpa-mode-TIMELAPSE" name="radio" value="TIMELAPSE" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="system-fpa-mode-TIMELAPSE" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Timelapse</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="system-fpa-mode-CONTINUOUS" name="radio" value="CONTINUOUS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="system-fpa-mode-CONTINUOUS" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Continuous</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="system-fpa-mode-RAMP_AND_HOLD" name="radio" value="RAMP_AND_HOLD" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" checked="checked">
    <label for="system-fpa-mode-RAMP_AND_HOLD" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false">    <span class="ui-button-text">Ramp and Hold</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="system-modes-stillimage" class="ui-buttonset">
    <input type="radio" id="system-stillimage-mode-TIMELAPSE" name="radio" value="TIMELAPSE" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="system-stillimage-mode-TIMELAPSE" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false">    <span class="ui-button-text">Timelapse</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="system-stillimage-mode-CONTINUOUS" name="radio" value="CONTINUOUS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="system-stillimage-mode-CONTINUOUS" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Continuous</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="system-stillimage-mode-RAMP_AND_HOLD" name="radio" value="RAMP_AND_HOLD" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="system-stillimage-mode-RAMP_AND_HOLD" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-state-active ui-corner-right" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">Ramp and Hold</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var continuousButton = $('#system-fpa-mode-CONTINUOUS');
continuousButton.prop('checked', true);

// try uncommenting the following two lines to see the first set of radio buttons lose their value
//var stillimageButton = $('#system-stillimage-mode-CONTINUOUS');
//stillimageButton.prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bYk6y/10/

When the second update is called, the first radio group loses it's value.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only have one radio group. They all have `name="radio"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `name` attributes:

The first group should be something like

```
name="radio1"
```

And the second

```
name="radio2"
```

Comment: You caught the error, so I'm giving you credit.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @mikeboldischar My pleasure. We all run into little things like that now and again.

Answer (score 0):

A radio group is all the buttons that have the same `name` attribute. It doesn't matter if they're in different DIVs. If you want the two groups to be separate, you have to give them different names. So the first group could be:

```
name="radio-fpa"
```

and the second would be:

```
name="radio-stillimage"
```